# Bulk merge items sub-folders into new folder

Tags: terminal, finder, macos

I have a main folder with about 80 folders in, each with about 10 items in. I want to be able to use a Terminal command or something to just move every item from each sub-folder into a new one (i.e the newly created folder would have around 800 items in, not separated by individual folders). Doing this by hand would be very tedious. Is there a way to do it easily and quickly? I have looked at [`ditto`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html), but couldn't figure out how to use it for my use case. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the structure is like

```
main-folder
    subfolder-1
        item-1
        item-2
    subfolder-2
        item-3
        item-4
```

and all the items are uniquely named, you can use

```
cd main-folder
mkdir ../target-folder
mv */* ../target-folder/
```

to move everything into a target folder on the same directory level as the main folder. If you just want to move everything into the main folder, just use

```
cd main-folder
mv */* .
```

Comment: `mv */* .` worked perfectly, thank you! So easy :)